# Loading Product List Withing Module Configuration Section?

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, product-attribute, dashboard, extension-attributes

I've been asked to write a module which gives the option to add a simple (string) value to one or more products in the store.

I've created this functionality to add the attribute by editing an individual product. But it's been requested that the user should also be able to edit any product through the module's settings in **Stores > Configuration > MyModule**.

I have not seen this done in any other module so I would like to know if this is possible?

Eg:

In **Stores > Configuration > MyModule > Settings**, a table would be displayed showing every product for that store, with the option to set a value or a null value for the "my_attribute" field for that product.

Is this is something that is doable / good practice in magento 2, or would this sort of thing always be done through the "Products" view?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to load any entities within the configuration.
I would recommend doing it trough the Products list view in order to keep it consistent with Magento standards.

However, to answer your question:
It is possible, but not at all recommended and it would require a lot of overriding of core file since the config section is generated code from XML.

If your client insists on having it separate from **Catalog->Product** list, I would recommend creating [a new page for this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html).

However, as I understand, you created an attribute in order to add the value to the product. So why wouldn't your customer just use Mass update which is default magento?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and keep it in the product view.

not quite sure how mass update works in magento 2, you say it is available by default? have seen functions that seem to handle mass updating of attributes but not sure how you're supposed to enable changing the values in the product list view?

Comment: You can select the products you wish to edit from **Catalog -> Product** list and in the Actions dropdown find the "Update Attribute" option.

Comment: ^ Thanks, just seen how to do that! There is no way though to do a "mass update" with different values, for the same attribute, for different products though - I would have to create the functionality for that myself? Eg if the products > catalog view took user input for each attribute, and then you just hit an "update" button after changing whichever values you wanted?

Comment: I'm afraid you  can't. You would need to create that functionality. But again,I would recommend creating a separate page for it. ( Tutorial link in answer )

Comment: Hi again :-)

Have done all the page creation stuff, however I'm now not sure what is the best approach to get something similar to the "native" list of products in that page, but make it writeable? IE should I locally overwrite the product_listing.xml component, add my extra fields, and amend the controller somehow, or should I build my own ui component from the ground up?